# how to make your asp.net web application available on your pc/laptops IP address for other computers to access

Tags: asp.net, iis, hosting, lan, static-ip-address

So I'm using visual studio 2013 and mysql server management studio on my windows 8.1 laptop.

I have created an asp.net web application involving file uploading, downloading and de/en-cryption.

I want this asp application to be available on my laptop's IP address so that when I connect it to a LAN, I can use another pc to access that application by basically just browsing the IP address of my laptop.

Can anyone help me with this. I tried searching for this but couldn't come up with anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio’s built-in ASP.NET Development Server has the benefit of being light-weight and easy to quickly run but doesn't listen to the remort ports.So just install other webserver on your local machine and work with it.

Best way is, host your ASP.Net site on IIS webServer.

IIS is a microsoft development. So that install it and you can check wether installation is okay, by using `http://localhost`

If you want more help inform me

Comment: Thank u for ur suggestion. Based on that i did some study and here is what i did.
1 Installed the IIS components
2 Opened IIS manager, created the application pool and added my app to it.
3] when i ran the web app, it successfully opened the Login page as i wanted.(thanks once again)
4] HOWEVER when I input the username and password and clicked on login i'm getting an error..(i'm comparing the username and password with the data stored in a MySQL database of all users, on successful authentication the user is transferred to the next page)

Can you help me with this.

Comment: This is the error I'm getting...

Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\sahi'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\sahi'.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.